# Почему у SO Ru разные значки в хроме и на сайте

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, stackoverflow

На сайте у SO вот такой значок:[image: введите сюда описание изображения], а в закладках хрома вот такой:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тж. см. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252622/less-confusing-icons-for-localized-stack-overflow-sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У локализованных сайтов SO (русский, японский, испанский, португальский) значки (favicon) разных цветов. А на большой эмблеме везде одинаковые. Так уж сложилось. Вопрос к дизайнерам в общем. То есть, не [дефект], а [так-задумано].