# Отсутствие единообразия иконок Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: предложение, дизайн, интерфейс

Почему цветовая схема иконки в шапке - такая же как на англоязычном сайте, а во всех остальных местах использования - синяя (список подфорумов, чат комнаты, иконка во вкладке браузера и т.д.)? Отсутствие единообразия вызывает когнитивный диссонанс.

Сильнее всего бросается в глаза разница в шапке и во вкладке браузера:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю прийти к единообразию и использовать в шапке сайта синюю иконку.

Аналогичная история и со всеми другими локальными so-сообществами.

Comment: Синяя бы там так себе смотрелась...

Comment: @Qwertiy это потому что цветовая схема используется со старшего сайта, её использование - тоже сомнительная вещь

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему у SO Ru разные значки в хроме и на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5699/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%83-so-ru-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)